# Bubble Chart using ggplotly - Changing the labels using a slider

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, bubble-chart

First of all here is my data:

```
df <- structure(list(rowname = c(
  "AA - 2018", "AA - 2019", "AA - 2020",
  "AB - 2018", "AB - 2019", "AB - 2020"
), Class = c(
  "AA", "AA",
  "AA", "AB", "AB", "AB"
), Year = c(
  2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2018L,
  2019L, 2020L
), Vol = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7), Profit = c(
  -0.1,
  -0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, -0.9
), Amount = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I am trying to create a bubble chart where the size of the bubble is dependent on the amount and is positioned based on the profitability (as a % of the amount) on the x-axis and the volatility (as a % of the amount) on the y-axis. I have added a slider that uses the year column so that the bubbles can change   as the slider changes year.

What i would like to do is introduce a label that uses the 'rowname' column as a label and it changes depending on the year that the slider is on. E.g. If the slider is on 2018 then one bubble will be labelled AA - 2018 and the other AB - 2018, once the slider changes to 2019 then the bubbles will be labelled AA - 2019 and AB - 2019 etc.

When i run the code below i get all the labels on all at the same time and it looks a complete mess.

Code is as follows:

```
Bound <- 0.05
y_high <- max(df$Vol) + Bound
   y_low <- 0

x_high <-max(df$Profit) + Bound
x_low <- min(df$Profit) - Bound

plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Profit, y = Vol, size = Amount, color = Class)) +
  geom_point(aes(frame = Year), alpha = 0.2) + scale_size(range = c(5,50)) +
  geom_text(label = rownames(df))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(y_low,y_high)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent,expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(x_low,x_high)) +
 

fig <- ggplotly(plot)

fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

1. You use the `frame` aes only in`geom_point`. Therefore the points vary by frame, but not the labels. To solve this put `frame = Year` in the global aes, i.e. inside `ggplot()`.
2. You want the labels to be equal to the column `rowname` but use `rownames(df)` instead. To solve this issue map `rowname` on `label`.

Try this:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Profit, y = Vol, size = Amount, color = Class, frame = Year)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_size(range = c(5, 50)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = rowname), size = 5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(y_low, y_high)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent, expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(x_low, x_high))

fig <- ggplotly(plot)

fig
```

[image]